# Git Website Deployment - Two Methods

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I've been researching git website deployment, and I have come across 2 different methods.  They both seem to work, but I am wondering what pros/cons that I am missing.  Which of these 2 methods do you use, and why?

1. Repo with detached work tree in public www directory.  You push to the repo and the post-update hook does a checkout -f (similar to [this](http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/#website))
2. Bare Repo AND non-bare repo in public www directory.  Post-update hook does a git reset and then a git pull. (similar to [this](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/))

Method 1 seems simpler, since you just have 1 repo to worry about, but I'm wondering if there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in most case if you are working alone, it make no difference.
If you are working with a team, the following may happen:

1. someone may make changes on the production server's www directory and you commit and push. The post-update hook will reset the public www directory and erase all his/her work.
2. he/she make changes on the production server and commit it. When you do a commit and push, His/her work will be in a repository branch, then he/she can just do a merge and all the work is there.

1 method is easy at the beginning but you risk the chance of losting some of your work.
 I hope that help, if I misunderstanding what you mean, please feel free to correct it.